# Ajax tile flow layout grid?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, grid, tile

I need a way to dynamically add customizable cells in a left-to-right direction, based on a given dataset.  Is there an ajax-type control that can accomplish this, or another approach?  Any ideas welcome-

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

How about using the telerik AJAX ListView for what you said? Check what it can do on the demos [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/listview/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: That's an ASP.NET solution- need a generic AJAX solution